# Generating a WCF client for MODIS Web Service

Tags: web-services, wcf, wsdl, soap-rpc-encoded

I want to create a WCF client for MODIS Web Service available on this website: http://daac.ornl.gov/MODIS/MODIS-menu/modis_webservice.html There is a link to WSDL file, which can I use to generate proxy class. The problem is, that this file is somehow malformed, I cannot create clients with .NET tools like Add Service Reference, wsdl.exe or svcutil.exe. When I try to generate proxy class through website, I get following response:

[image]

I've tried to download the WSDL file and create proxy class from local copy, but then I've got this error:

[image]

These errors are the same for Add Service Reference and for console output of wsdl.exe and svcutil.exe utils. Is there any other way to create a WCF client to this service or is it impossible in .NET?

EDIT-----
I've managed that the problem occurs, becouse the WSDL is in RPC/Endoded standard and .NET tools cannot handle it properly. I've tried to convert it to Document/literal standard but it's still not working. Can somebody look at my WSDL file and check what I have wrong? It's available under this link: https://wklej.to/67rR7

Answer (score 0):

removing wsdl:documentation blocks inside the element
tags helps to generating codes via svcutil.exe or wsdl.exe.

[Baseline](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1JR34332) for this solution

Hopes this helps.

Comment: It worked, thanks to this I created now a proxy class, but the service is returning only NULL. Can you create a client and check this?